# Why does (MonthName.format(c.get(Calendar.MONTH))) return wrong month?

Tags: java, calendar

I was trying out the Time class in Java and the following outputs December even though the system time shows March:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat MonthName = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
System.out.println(MonthName.format(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
```

But using this returns March:

```
System.out.println(MonthName.format(c.getTime()));
```

I am aware that the counting of months in JAVA begins from 0 and not 1 one so it displaying February would be appropriate but March?

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is a date formatter, not a month number formatter.

Comment: Try changing your date format pattern to include a day and year.

Answer (score 4):

Because `c.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns a number, and calling `format(number)` is the same as calling `format(new Date(number))` (check [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/DateFormat.java#294)).

In this case, `c.get(Calendar.MONTH)` returns `2`, because - as you said - this API uses 0-based months, so March is 2.

When you call `format(2)`, it's equivalent to calling `format(new Date(2))`, which means a date that corresponds to "2 milliseconds after [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)", which is `1970-01-01T00:00:00.002` (basically, 2 milliseconds after January 1st 1970 at midnight **in UTC**).

Then, this date (Jan 1st 1970 **UTC**) will be formatted by your `SimpleDateFormat`, which uses the JVM default timezone. So, when that date (that corresponds to Jan 1st in UTC) is converted to your JVM default timezone, gives you "December". Just print the value of `new Date(2)` and see what you get (spoiler: it'll be a date in December 31st 1969).

---

Your second attempt works because `c.getTime()` returns a `java.util.Date`, which in this case will correspond to March.

Answer (score 0):

The SimpleDateFormat expects a date, not a month number

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
Date d = c.getTime();
SimpleDateFormat MonthName = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");    
System.out.println(MonthName.format(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now()                  // Better to specify time zone explicitly: LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) )
    .getMonth                    // Get `Month` enum object appropriate to that date in that zone.
    .getDisplayName(             // Generate a `String`, the localized name of the month.
        FormatStyle.FULL ,       // Control how long or how abbreviated the text.
        Locale.CANADA_FRENCH     // Specify the human language and cultural norms to be applied in localizing.
    )
```

## java.time

The [Answer by posutes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49325322/642706) is correct.

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplanted the troublesome old legacy date-time classes (`Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`).

[`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) replaces `Calendar`, representing a moment on the timeline with the wall-clock time used by people of a certain region (a time zone), with a resolution of nanoseconds.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;   // Would be better to pass explicitly the desired/expected time zone rather than implicitly rely on the JVM’s current default.
```

Retrieve a [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum object for the month of this `ZonedDateTime` object’s date.

```
Month month = zdt.getMonth() ;
```

Generate a string for the name of the month, automatically localized. To localize, specify:

- [`TextStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/TextStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Ask for localized name of month.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH etc.
String monthName = month.getDisplayName( FormatStyle.FULL , locale ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).